# Ошибка при публикации проекта в AppStore с подключенным DevMate

Tags: xcode, mac, cocoa

Objective-C проект для Mac. Через Pod-файл подключено несколько библиотек, в том числе и DevMateKit_MAS. DevMateKit_MAS - вариант либы, специально реализованный для программ, публикуемых в AppStore.

Есть известная проблема и её решение, описанные в документации от производителя разделе "DevMateKit for Mac App Store" https://docs.devmate.com/v1.0/docs/integrate-devmate-kit

Инструкция по преодолению ошибки выполнена, но при попытке загрузки собранного приложения в AppStore сообщается о коллизии:

```
0 ERROR HMS-90511: "CFBundleldentifier Collision. The lnfo.plist CFBundleldentifier value ‘com.devmate.Problem-Reporter-
Sandboxed' of 'MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Problem Reporter
Sandboxed.app' is already in use by another application."
```

Проблема должна была решиться запуском скрипта update_reporter_id.sh, который входит в состав DevMateKit_MAS. Сборка проекта выполняется автоматизировано и в логе есть информация о его выполнении:

```
[10:32:11][Step 3/3] update_reporter_id script begin
[10:32:11][Step 3/3] /Users/administrator/Documents/buildAgent/work/6f02086ea02b954e/TM-OsX-debud-source/MyApp
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] Will check path "/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crzotizenxyjrbfhplvvtudqphnl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppOSX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Problem Reporter Sandboxed.app"
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crzotizenxyjrbfhplvvtudqphnl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppOSX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Problem Reporter Sandboxed.app: replacing existing signature
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crzotizenxyjrbfhplvvtudqphnl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppOSX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Problem Reporter Sandboxed.app: signed app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [myteam.myapp.com.devmate.Problem-Reporter-Sandboxed]
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crzotizenxyjrbfhplvvtudqphnl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppOSX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A: replacing existing signature
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] /Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-crzotizenxyjrbfhplvvtudqphnl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAppOSX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/Contents/Frameworks/DevMateKit.framework/Versions/A: signed bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64) [com.devmate.DevMateKit]
[10:32:12][Step 3/3] update_reporter_id script end
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте, правильный ли вы собираете таргет.

Каким образом Bundle Identifier вашего приложения оказался равным "com.devmate.Problem-Reporter-Sandboxed"?

Comment: Думаю, с bundle identifier всё нормально.
 "com.devmate.Problem-Reporter-Sandboxed" - это id не нашего приложения, а либы внутри devmate. Без devmate проект уже приняли на публикацию.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять bundleID DevMateKit_MAS с `com.devmate.Problem-Reporter-Sandboxed' на какой-то другой